# Run python test from project in the IntelliJ Ultimate IDE

Tags: python, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, python-behave

I am trying to execute my python based test cases in IntelliJ Idea. The test cases are in BDD style with [Behave](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) framework. 
I installed the python plug-in on my IntelliJ IDEA ultimate,
But when I try to execute the test cases, I get an error saying

```
Error: Could not find or load main class cucumber.api.cli.Main
```

Has anyone ever faced this kind of issue? Or has anyone used IntelliJ with the python plugin?

Any response would be of great help.

Comment: It looks you are using the wrong run/debug configuration for your tests, use the one that suits the Python specific tests, not the Cucumber Java configuration which you are trying to use now. Refer to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html.

Comment: (Off-topic) If you are using Python, why not use PyCharm?

Comment: Also, you seems adding a wrong Run Configuration. You need Python, not Java Application.

Comment: @GenoChen i have a license for IntelliJ and want to use the same. Also your question is not helping me solve my problem.

Comment: Also when I set  python sdk and run the scenarios, it says the jdk is not set. @CrazyCoder

Comment: @CrazyCoder when i change the run configurations, it say "No jdk specified" and does not execute my test cases.  :(

Comment: Don't use Java configurations that require JDK, create a Python module with Python SDK and use Python Run/Debug configuration.

Comment: @CrazyCoder are you sure he can run it just as python tests? I checked the documentation and tests with Behave looks like cucumber tests.

Comment: @EugenMartynov it works in PyCharm which doesn't know anything about Java: https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2014/09/feature-spotlight-behavior-driven-development-in-pycharm/. So, JDK is not needed to run these tests.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I changed the run configurations completely to python, that worked. Thanks a ton.